# "gcloud app deploy" skips too many files

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have 4 enviroments I'm working on a GAE project. 2 are windows enviroments, and the other is centos (6 and 7). I've installed GAE on both. For some strange reason, the same project when deployed from a linux enviroment, skips almost all my files, while the project deployed from windows, uploads all files. This has nothing to do with file changes, and the log, even in the debug level, only says:
 Skipping upload of [main.py]
 Skipping upload of [jsfile/desktop/f.js]
Any help you can offer?

Comment: Unlikely, but not impossible for the 2 SDK versions (windows and linus) to diverge in the `skip_files` default values. Try adding such section to your `.yaml` files explicitly (with care, as that will overwrite the defaults). See `skip_files` section in the syntax table: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appref#syntax. If this addition fixes things then it confirms it's an SDK bug.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. While it does look like a bug (as it runs well on windows, and problematic on linux), changing the skip file changed nothing. However, I found another way to handle this issue, I'll just leave it be.

Comment: @GuruYaya can you post the solution for your problem please i have same issue and i can't fix it